# How to drag-select multiple files in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, file-management, drag-and-drop

Here's what I do know:
I can click to select a file
I can click SHIFT to select a range
I can use COMMAND to add or subtract from and existing selection
I can select by clicking on an **empty space** and dragging.

However, I'd like to know if there's a way to start a drag-select by clicking and dragging over files, not over an empty space. I'd like to drag over a file to **select** it and other files in its vicinity, not to move the file around. I imagined I could do that by clicking OPTION or COMMAND while starting a selection over files, but that didn't work.

Is there a way to achieve that natively or by using a plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to achieve this in Finder.

Other than e.g. on Windows, on OS X you can initiate element drags without having them selected first, just by pressing the mouse button down. This is the behavior in *all* applications (even Java-based).

Both `Option` and `Command` are used to modify drag behavior: `Command` forces move (e.g. to another volume), while `Option` forces copy.

In OS X Lion, the selection behavior changed a little though: Selection of multiple ranges is no longer possible using a drag, AFAIK. Starting with the second part, you need to select the first file of the second range, then release `Command`, press `Shift`, and select the last file of that range.

---

You still have the option to initiate the drag over an empty space (e.g. just next to the icon, or between icon and label, in icon view), or non-filename columns in list view. Since these are plenty, there's probably no sufficient reason for Apple to implement the behavior you want here.